# Refactoring simple algorithm with side effects to FP style - update task status

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

We have this basic algorithm, which is written in imperative style:

```
const db = new DB()

const markAsCompleted = ( taskId ) => {
    // Mark the task as completed
    db.markTaskAsCompleted( taskId )

    // Update parent status 
    const parentId = db.getTaskParentId( taskId )
    if ( parentId ) {

        // Get parent's incomplete children
        const isIncomplete = ( task ) => task.status != 'completed'
        const parentChildren = db.getTaskChildren( parentId )
        const incompleteTasks = parentChildren.filter( isIncomplete )

        // If all children have completed, mark the parent as completed
        if ( incompleteTasks.length === 0 ) {
            db.markTaskAsCompleted( taskId ) // Simple case - no recursion
            // markAsCompleted( parentId ) // Complex case - with recursion
        }
    }
}
```

The db operations all involve side-effects (obviously).

How can this be converted to functional programming style? That is, a point-free style based on function composition, whilst using the `IO` monad and having the client 'pulling the trigger' on side-effects. As in this [piece of code](https://github.com/ramda/ramda-fantasy/blob/master/docs/IO.md):

```
loudCat = argsIO.chain(R.traverse(IO.of, readFile))
                .map(R.join('\n'))
                .map(R.toUpper)
                .chain(stdoutWrite);

loudCat.runIO();
```

Preferably, the solution will use either [ramda-fantasy](https://github.com/ramda/ramda-fantasy) or [folktale](http://folktalejs.org/).

Also note the two cases:

- *simple* with no recursion (uncommented)
- *complex* with recursion (commented)

Comment: Make sure to use `if (children.every(isCompleted))` not that horrible filter+length solution

Answer (score 0):

Usually db lookups are async and therefore the async adt is used instead of the io adt, but as you asked for the io...

Create a wrapper around your db that can return ios of your computations, then chain away:

```
// replace return values of these functions with your actual db lookups
const db = {
    getTaskChildren: (taskId) => IO.of([]),
    getTaskParentId: (taskId) => IO.of('123'),
    markTaskAsCompleted: (taskId) => IO.of(1),
};

const checkParent = (parentId) =>
    db.getTaskChildren(parentId)
        .map((children) =>
            children.filter(({ status }) => status !== 'completed'))
        .chain((incomplete) =>
            incomplete.length === 0
                ? db.markTaskAsCompleted(parentId)
                : IO.of(null)); // do nothing

const markAsCompleted = (taskId) =>
    db.markTaskAsCompleted(taskId)
        .chain(() => db.getTaskParentId(taskId))
        .chain(checkParent);

markAsCompleted('abc').run();
```

The flow shouldnt change if the io is swapped for async.